# Website, hosting server and Local PC work as one

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, project, exe

I have a super simple site that I want to host locally. **I want to be able to trigger windows program from the website** and return the results to the website.

> **How can I accomplish this? 
> Is this even possible?**

I will be hosting locally on a dedicated pc for family and friends. The windows software is a automated bot like [autoMe](http://www.asoftech.com/autome/) it has a series of actions that it will do to attain answers.

The answers I want to return back to the webpage. (text 5 int characters max)

**How can I do this locally?**

*Is this possible if I Host site on a commercial server and keep automated bot local?*

Comment: This is possible:
http://us1.php.net/function.exec

You may be able to capture output of specific processes and return them to your php runtime where you could do with it what you wanted on your server. How secure it is, though, is entirely a product of implementation and execution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [wampp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [xampp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/)  - This will enable to run a server on your local machine.
2. Use PHP's `exec` or `system` (or backtiks) to activate any exe on your windows machines. You will need to give proper permissions to Apache to run that exe though.
3. Make sure your computer is not accessible to the world, otherwise, anyone can access your machine easily.